# Keyboard navigation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, keyboard, navigation

I'm trying to add some keyboard support for a website I'm working on and I found these plugins for jQuery: [shortKeys](http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/shortkeys/) and jquery.hotkeys (can't post link because i'm a new user). The thing is I want to make it so that when a user presses "j", for example, to go to a different page, "about.html", for example, but, I don't know how to make that happen. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any jquery plugin for this purpose, following piece of code should suffice:

```
$( document ).keydown(function(event)
{
  switch(event.which)
  {
    case 74: // 74 is keycode for j
      window.location = 'somewhere.html';
      break;

    case 75: // 75 is keycode for k
      window.location = 'another.html';
      break;
  }
});
```

You can find keycodes of all keys here http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) in conjunction with either plugin, like this for [shortKeys](http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/shortkeys/):

```
$(document).shortkeys({
 'J': function () { window.location = 'about.html'; },
 'K': function () { window.location = 'somethingElse.html'; }
});
```

Or, using [Hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/):

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'j', function() {
  window.location = 'about.html';
});
```

Comment: @Victor - welcome :) be sure to accept answers if they resolve your question to close these out :)